# how to add a delete button for every single element in a list with javascript

Tags: javascript, html

So I'm learning javascript of a tutorial on YouTube. In the tutorial they have a delete all button. I don't want to delete all of the list items. Basically I'm trying to make a item tracker. I can input a item and its location and save it. And when I move that object I can delete the old post and update the information. I want a delete button for every single item on the list instead of just delete all. I'm not very good at explaining.

https://github.com/bl0ssom/chrome-extension-list-holder.git
code in GitHub.

Comment: doubt the code works with `lenght` along with other typos.

Comment: Should this `const inputBtn = document.getElementById("input-ban")` be `const inputBtn = document.getElementById("input-btn")`? Notice `ban` vs. `btn`

Comment: First step, actually get that code to run. Second step, add a button to the li. Third create a function that removes the li and element from the array.

Comment: There is a typo: `const ulEl = document.getElementByID("ul-el")` -> `...getElementById...`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check this Code out

```js
let myLeads = {} // Empty JS Object Where URL will be stored
const inputEl = document.getElementById("input-el"); // Getting the text Input element
const inputBtn = document.getElementById("input-btn"); // Getting the save button
const ulEl = document.getElementById("ul-el"); // Get the 'ul' element
const leadsFromLocalStorage = JSON.parse( localStorage.getItem("myLeads") ); // Loading data from localstorage
const tabBtn = document.getElementById("tab-btn"); // IDK what this button does

if (leadsFromLocalStorage != undefined) { // Checking if the localstorage is not empty
    myLeads = leadsFromLocalStorage // if there is data in localstorage which we already parsed it should be assigned to the empty JS Object `myLeads`
    for (var uid in myLeads) { render(uid); } // Running a for loop which will render all the URL inside our object one by one
}

// This function simply returns a random 16 Alphabet long string
function randomGUID() {
    let uid = 'xxxxxxxx-xxxx-4xxx-yxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx'.replace(/[xy]/g, function(c) { var r = Math.random() * 16 | 0, v = c == 'x' ? r : (r & 0x3 | 0x8); return v.toString(16); });
    if (uid in myLeads) randomGUID();
    else return uid;
}

// This function will simply save all the URLs by converting them into string and then saving it in LocalStorage
function saveList() { localStorage.setItem("myLeads", JSON.stringify(myLeads)) }

function removeElement(element) { // This function is used for removing any URL
    delete myLeads[element.parentNode.id]; // this will get the unique id of the URL and using that unique ID it will remove it from our JS object `myLeads`
    document.getElementById(element.parentNode.id).remove(); // Then simply remove that element from our HTML
    saveList(); // Finally Save everything to localstorage
}

// IDK about what this does and i haven't even touched it
tabBtn.addEventListener("click", function() {
    chrome.tabs.query({active: true, currentWindow: true}, function(tabs) {
        myLeads.push(tabs[0].url);
        localStorage.setItem("myLeads", JSON.stringify(myLeads) );
        render(myLeads);
    })
});

// This function will add a element on our page with it's respective URL
function render(uid) { // It takes a unique string "uid" as a parameter
    let text = myLeads[uid]; // then using the unique string we get the URL from our JS Object and getting the text respective to that string in our object
  
  // Then this will simply make a new "li" element
    let listElement = document.createElement("li");
    listElement.setAttribute("id", uid); // and then set it's ID to the Unique string we got as parameter

    let linkElement = document.createElement("a"); // then making a simple Link element
    linkElement.setAttribute("target", "_blank"); // Setting it's target so that it opens in a new tab
    linkElement.setAttribute("href", text); // setting up the URL of that element
    linkElement.innerText = text; // and also the text

  // Making a button and assiging a onclick event to it
    let buttonElement = document.createElement("button");
    buttonElement.setAttribute("onclick", "removeElement(this);");
    buttonElement.innerText = "Remove";

  // adding all this to our HTML
    listElement.appendChild(linkElement);
    listElement.appendChild(buttonElement);
    ulEl.appendChild(listElement);
}

// simply adding a event listener which will run a function when the button with ID - 'input-btn' is clicked
inputBtn.addEventListener("click", function() {
    uid = randomGUID(); // first getting a random Unique string for Identification
    myLeads[uid] = inputEl.value; // then adding the unique string and the value given by user to our JS object `myLeads`
    inputEl.value = ""; // Emptying the input element
    render(uid); // Rendering that element
    saveList(); // and then saving everything to local storage
});
```

```css
/* Not changed much, just fixed some buttons */
body {
    margin: 0; padding: 10px; min-width: 400px;
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}

input {
    width: 100%; padding: 10px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    border: 1px solid #5f9345;
    margin-bottom: 4px;
}

button {
    background: #5f9345; color: white;
    padding: 10px 20px; border: none;
  font-weight: bold;
}

ul { margin-top: 20px; list-style: none; padding-left: 0; }
li { margin-top: 5px; }
li button { margin-left: 10px; }
a { color:#5f9345; text-decoration: none; }
```

```html
<input type="text" id="input-el">
<button id="input-btn" >SAVE INPUT</button>
<button id="tab-btn">SAVE TAB</button>
<ul id="ul-el"></ul>
```

If you try to run this in stackoverflow it will not work due to security reasons but it will work on production & development enviroment!

Comment: WOW! outstanding, that worked really well until whenever I press the remove button it removes the item from the screen but whenever I hit input again with a different item it comes back because it is still in local storage. Do u know how to remove it from the screen and local storage? if not its fine.

Comment: I have added a full complete working code, with local storage and all thing working, hope you understand the code or else tell me i'll explain everything

Comment: ok yes works exactly how I want it to work also plz explain my dumb brain cannot comprehend this code

Comment: I have edited the JS code with comments that explain everything, I hope it is not complicated